# Push messages from code behind to client using SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am importing records from an excel spreadsheet.  I want to update the client screen with the progress of each record.  I was advised that SignalR is the way ahead.

I've started with the ChatHub example and stripped it back a bit.

***Edit...***
It appears that the `broadcastMessage` function is working, but is behaving strangely.  Here's a short video of what is happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRqiyaQ2hD0

**ASPX Page**

```
<form id="form2" runat="server">

    <ul id="progressReport"></ul>

    <asp:Button Text="Push message" ID="btn" OnClick="btn_Click" runat="server" />

    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>

    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                // Html encode display name and message. 
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                // Add the message to the page. 
                $('#progressReport').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };

            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
            });
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
using SignalRChat;
using System;

namespace SignalR_Test
{
    public partial class form2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChatHub ch = new ChatHub();
            for ( int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                ch.Send("Code Behind", i +" has been imported");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ChatHub.CS**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your aspx page and check if it's logging the calls in the javascript console:

```
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
$.connection.hub.start();
```

Your class is called `ChatHub` and you are doing a `connection.chatHub` in your client side (notice the lowercase `c` vs uppercase). Try adding a `HubName` attribute to your `Hub` class:

```
[HubName("chatHub")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
```

Also, try adding `~/` to your script src:

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The console reports no errors - and the last message is: SignalR: Invoked chathub.Send... I discovered that with 2 browsers something unexpected was happening. I think this relates to the fact I started with the Chat demo. (video here: http://youtu.be/8pg5jV-nxMQ?hd=1)

Comment: Adding [HubName("chatHub")] in that position produces 2 errors: The type or namespace name 'HubNameAttribute' could not be found
The type or namespace name 'HubName' could not be found

Comment: add this to your using statements `using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;`

Comment: @wotney I think your video got deleted for being a duplicate. I can't view it.

Comment: *Really* appreciate the help !... I've updated the link to the video

Comment: @wotney, so after seeing the video, not sure what you mean by `unexpected`? It looks like it's working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55573/discussion-between-wotney-and-sofanatic).

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing required `Startup` class? See example [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20).

Do JS scripts versions(jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js, jquery-1.8.2.min.js)  match with scripts that you have in 'Scripts' directory?

Comment: Sorry, the Startup class is present.  I haven't adjusted that, so forgot to mention it !

Comment: What about scripts versions(html vs. scripts dir)?

Comment: The scripts are all being referenced properly from what I can see.  I've edited my question with a link to a video to show what's happening.